# Meson version in Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, meson-build

Earlier I compiled project i.MX Linux Yocto Project BSP 4.14.78_1.0.0 Release version and it was OK. I didn't update the project and all enviroment is installed on linux build computer. But now I have error like below.
Log data follows:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| The Meson build system
| Version: 0.44.1
| Source dir: /home/local/user/imx-yocto-bsp1/build-wayland-imx8qmmek/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/vkmark/1.0-r0/git
| Build dir: /home/local/user/imx-yocto-bsp1/build-wayland-imx8qmmek/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/vkmark/1.0-r0/build
| Build type: cross build
| 
| Meson encountered an error in file meson.build, line 1, column 0:
| Meson version is 0.44.1 but project requires >=0.45.
|
```

Is it meson from toolchain or from build OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/72132/ you're most likely using the Sumo release of Yocto. Thud onwards have 0.45.  Considering Sumo isn't supported anymore I'd considering upgrading your Yocto/BSP.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How to update just meson package without updating poky?

Comment: Carefully. You'll need to update the recipe and the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's the toolchain meson: You don't mention the Yocto/oe-core version but based on the meson version it seems a couple of years old. If you managed to build a version of 'vkmark' before then it almost certainly means that the version you built did not require this meson version but the version you are building now does.